# TypeError : KeyCode object is not 'callable'?

Tags: python, automation, click, pynput

So I was trying to make an auto clicker using Pynput module that could be toggled on or off with a key
I don't know exactly why but upon pressing the trigger for turning it on i.e. "c" in this case, it shows a bunch of errors mainly referring to - KeyCode object is not 'callable' and Unhandled exception in listener callback
[these are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seHBj.png)

the code goes like this..

```
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
import time 
TriggerAutoClicker = KeyCode(char = "c")
    AutoClickerstate = False
    mouse = Controller()

    def autoclick():
        while True:
            mouse.click(button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.01)
    def toggling(key):
        if key == TriggerAutoClicker:
            global AutoClickerstate
            AutoClickerstate = not AutoClickerstate
            
    click_thread = threading.Thread(target = autoclick)
    click_thread.start
    with Listener(on_press = TriggerAutoClicker) as listener :
        listener.join()
```

kindly please point out any errors in the above script or provide a better alternative for performing the task